# Studying a limit of integrals- sns admission test

Tags: integration, limits

Let $ A=\{(r, \theta )| 2\le r\le 3, \theta \in [0,2 \pi ) \}$ and $ F : A \to A$ such that $F(r, \theta )=(r, (r \theta) \; \mathrm{mod} \;(2 \pi ))$.
Considering a continuous function $g$, show the existence of $ \displaystyle \lim _{n \to \infty}$ $\int _{A} g(F^{(n)}) (x) dx$, where $F^{(n)}=F \circ F \circ ... \circ F $.

I've been able to prove that $F$ is not continuous only on $ \{(r,\theta) \, | \,r \in (2,3), \theta=0\} $.
After that I have shown that, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $F^{(n)}$ is Riemann integrable,    so $g(F^{(n)}) $ is too.

I think that the limit does not always exist, but I am not able to find a counter-example.
Thank you.

Comment: Let $h(r) = \int_0^{2\pi} g(r, \theta)\,d\theta$. What can you prove about how $\int_0^{2\pi}g\circ F^n(r, \theta)\,d\theta$ compares to $h(r)$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair i think that $2^n \le \int_{0}^{2 \pi } g \circ F^n(r, \theta ) d \theta$  $/h(r) \le 3^n$, but i'm not sure about this result.

Comment: Because $g$ is continuous on $A$ and $A$ is compact (closed and bounded), $g$ has a minimum value $m$ and maximum value $M$ it takes on. Note that $m \le g \circ F^n \le M$ also holds. What does this tell you about how $\int_0^{2\pi}g\circ F^n(r,\theta)\,d\theta$ behaves?

Comment: So i get that the sequence $\int _{A} g \circ F^n$ is limited, but it does not tell me anything about its behaviour.

Comment: Sure it does. For starters, being limited is in itself a behavior.  More importantly, it tells you that your previous calculation is false. You should look into what you did wrong. Thirdly, it tells you that the sequence at very least has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but how can i use this information to get an answer at the exercise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111890/discussion-between-francesco-trig-and-paul-sinclair).